# Livewire validate function got stuck on unique validation

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to validate a field for unique value. The validate function throws proper validation errors When I enter incorrect/duplicate values but the execution got stuck in validate method and not coming below to `dd('save called')` when I enter correct/unique values.

I have tried `protected $rules[]`, and `protected function rules()` but result is the same.

**Note: when I remove the unique rule from validation then everything works fine.**

here is component code.

```
public function savePaper($rowIndex)
{
    $this->validate([
        'rows.*.p1' => ['required', Rule::unique('dutysheets', 'p1')->ignore($this->row['id'])],         
    ]);
    dd('save called');
    $row = $this->rows[$rowIndex] ?? NULL;
    if (!is_null($row)) {
        optional(DutySheet::find($row['id']))->update($row);
    }
    $this->editedRowIndex = null;
    $this->editedPaper = null;
}
```

and here is the view code.

```
 @foreach ($rows as $index => $row)
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">
                    <input type="number" style="max-width: 60px;"
                    wire:model.differ="rows.{{ $index }}.p1"
                    wire:click="editPaper({{ $index }}, 'p1')"
                    wire:keydown.enter="savePaper({{ $index }})"
                    
                    />
                    @if ($editedPaper === $index . '.p1')
                        @error('rows.' . $index . '.p1')
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                {{ $message }}
                            </div>
                        @enderror
                        @endif
                    </td>
```

Comment: If the table is relatively large and the rows are also numerous this will be quite inefficient because it will execute one query per row. It might be more efficient to do `if (DB::table('dutysheets')->whereIn('p1', Arr::pluck(request()->rows, 'p1'))->exists()) { fail validation }`

Comment: @apokryfos: The table has less then 1 thousand rows.